# trying to understand:Fetches results from the database with each row keyed according to preference

Tags: php, mysql

```
/**
     * Fetches results from the database with each row keyed according to preference.
     * The 'key' parameter provides the column name with which to key the result.
     * For example, calling fetchAllKeyed('SELECT item_id, title, date FROM table', 'item_id')
     * would result in an array keyed by item_id:
     * [$itemId] => array('item_id' => $itemId, 'title' => $title, 'date' => $date)
     *
     * Note that the specified key must exist in the query result, or it will be ignored.
     *
     * @param string SQL to execute
     * @param string Column with which to key the results array
     * @param mixed Parameters for the SQL
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetchAllKeyed($sql, $key, $bind = array())
    {
        $results = array();
        $i = 0;

        $stmt = $this->_getDb()->query($sql, $bind, Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $i++;
            $results[(isset($row[$key]) ? $row[$key] : $i)] = $row;
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

Above code snippet is taken from xenforo system.

Question:

Although there is comments on this function, still did not understand how does 'key' parameter work?
In comments, it is said:

```
 * For example, calling fetchAllKeyed('SELECT item_id, title, date FROM table', 'item_id')
 * would result in an array keyed by item_id:
 * [$itemId] => array('item_id' => $itemId, 'title' => $title, 'date' => $date)

so if the table looks like this:
item_id   title     date
1         book      2000
2         car       2000
3         laptop    2001
...
```

so what result would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting array is an associative array with index as its corresponding `item_id`.

So the result will be

```
[1]=>array('item_id' => 1, 'title' => 'book', 'date' => '2000'),
[2]=>array('item_id' => 2, 'title' => 'car', 'date' => '2000'),
[3]=>array('item_id' => 3, 'title' => 'laptop', 'date' => '2001'),
......
```

Comment: so if I want to access the item: title:car, i should do [2]['title'],right?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, key() returns the index element of the current array position. More deeply is The **key()** function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, key() returns NULL.

More details on here http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php